How to Power 2 MG996R Tower Pro Servo
I tried powering a MG996R Tower Pro (180 deg metal gear) servo from an Arduino UNO and ended up hibernating the host PC.
I want to power two such motors (in parallel configuration) for 10 minutes a day at a time. What is the best solution to power it? I have learned the hard way that Arduino UNO's 5 V pin is not enough and it may have damaged my board, too.
Should I use a 6 V charging adapter and cut off its end connect it to the motor? Should I use a capacitor? What am I supposed to do to power two such motors simultaneously?
If possible, provide a schematic of how to connect my motors (series or parallel) with the power supply.
Side-question: How can I check if my Arduino board is damaged after drawing too much current from the servo because right now it works fine and is not heating and nothing seems charred.
